# Mongo db is not connecting

Tags: mongodb, drupal, mongodb-query, connection, connection-string

I have drupal8 application where I use various dbs. When i try to connect with mongo db by giving username and password, connection is not happening. I could connect with mongo db by mentioning server address alone.

note: mongodb is configured with username and password in my server
I tried below methods.

```
$this->connect_string = 'mongodb://user:password@serveraddress';  (not connecting)             
$this->connect_string = 'mongodb://serveraddress';        (connecting)        
#$this->connect_string = 'mongodb://user:password@serveraddress:27017/?authSource=dbname';(not connecting)
```

Php v-7.4, Drupal 8

developed custom module to connect with mongo db, to display news feed (news feed related information stored in mongo db).

how to pass user name & password to connect with mongo db?
Could not find any error logs in mongodb server.

Comment: Did you restart the MongoD after enabling authorisation?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes .I did